# Can I start Android App not in FullScreen mode?

Tags: java, android

I saw that youtube app can minimize to small window that displays over all other windows.
I want to do the same with my app.
What strings in manifest (or any other string) do it?

Thanks,

I am about this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at google documentation about this topic, it is called [picture-in-picture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the first two lines to your activity which will handle Picture in Picture (PIP) mode.
The third line needs to be added so that your activity will not relaunch once layout changes occur, such as device screen rotation.

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
```

You can find more information about this in the android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture).
Here is a [tutorial](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-o-tutorial-picture-in-picture-pip/) on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following tutorials which are nice to understand
`picture in picture` feature

https://medium.com/@mujtahidah/making-picture-in-picture-android-4120ac73efb4
http://www.zoftino.com/android-picture-in-picture-mode-example